# How to tell whether a field is required or not in Apex by describe fields

Tags: describesobject

I want to know how I tell whether a field is required or not in an Apex controller.

In my controller I get the record id and then get the object of that record by a describe call, then I get all the fields of that object, but I am not able to tell which field is required and which is not.

Answer (score 16):

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult r = User.sObjectType.getDescribe();
    Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> M = r.fields.getMap();
    for(String fieldName : M.keySet())
    { 
        Schema.SObjectField field = M.get(fieldName);
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult F = field.getDescribe();
        // A nillable field can have empty content. 
        // A isNillable Boolean non-nillable field must have a value for 
        // the object to be created or saved. 
        // If F.isNillable() is false then field is mandatory
        Boolean isFieldreq  = F.isNillable() ;
        System.debug ('F = ' + fieldName + ' isnul= ' +  isFieldreq);
    }
```

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm

Isnillable identifes whether the field is mandatory or not .If nillable then not mandatory else mandatory.

Comment: I think there is more to this than checking 'isNillable'. For example, all checkboxes have isNillable = false but they aren't necessarily required fields.

Comment: Good point on the checkboxes! You can check for data types!

Answer (score 12):

You can check this by global describe :

```
    public Boolean hasField(String objectname, fieldname)
    {
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult r =  gd.get(objectname).getDescribe();
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> FsMap = r.fields.getMap();
        if(FsMap.containsKey(fieldname))
        {
            Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldDetails = FsMap.get(fieldname).getDescribe();
            return fieldDetails.isNillable() ;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: The above solution is good. But what if i want to check for 1000 fields. We need to call the global describe method 1000 times. Won't that cause an issue. How many describe calls we can do? Will that not effect heap size and cpu execution time?

Comment: @sandeepch it is just a code snippet. You can modify its parameters to get single instance of global describe. Parameters can be made common or put outside of method.

Comment: I think there is more to this than checking 'isNillable'. For example, all checkboxes have isNillable = false but they aren't necessarily required fields.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a clean and complete function that avoids both system fields and checkboxes:

```
static Boolean isRequired(DescribeFieldResult describeFieldResult) {
    return describeFieldResult.isCreateable() && !describeFieldResult.isNillable() && describeFieldResult.getType() != DisplayType.BOOLEAN;
}
```

Examples:

```
System.debug(isRequired(Account.Name.getDescribe())); // True
System.debug(isRequired(Account.CreatedDate.getDescribe())); // False
System.debug(isRequired(Account.IsPartner.getDescribe())); // False
System.debug(isRequired(Account.BillingStreet.getDescribe())); // False
```

Comment: This is the most accurate answer

Answer (score 2):

7+ years still no concrete solution to the problem. Adding comments for those people who
Calling apex from LWC just to check if the field is required, Use getObjectInfo() UI-API adapter which returns a list of described fields for given sObject name, It contains a key "required" which serves the purpose.