# How to query required fields using SOQL

Tags: soql

How do I find out what fields are required when I create a record in Salesforce using SOQL?

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16101/how-get-field-is-required-or-not-in-apex-by-discribe-fields

Answer (score 3):

Joshua, I assume you're trying to do this programmatically in Apex. If so, you should be able to leverage [Accessing All Field Describe Results for an sObject](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_describe_objects_understanding.htm#apex_describe_object_all_fields)  and [Describe Field Result Methods](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm) to compile the list you're looking for, without even having to use SOQL: http://carvingintheclouds.blogspot.com/2013/09/listing-required-fields-for-object-in.html

Comment: I'm not using Apex do query, but the `REST API` in a `Ruby on Rails` application.

Comment: Hello, @JoshuaSmock, you can still use describe information via a REST API request. You can use Workbench to test this out and examine the raw JSON response from such a request, as **erbdex** suggested. Here's a quick video showing you how it's done (minus the last part where you are supposed to click the "Show Raw Response" link) at the top: http://screencast.com/t/k4BpXt8WNTjr

Answer (score 0):

Enter [Salesforce Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/).

In case you're not bound on `Apex` and are using the `REST API`, you can visualize all the fields and even generate queries. Also, you can run your custom queries.