# How to identify Required fields via the API

Tags: api, metadata-api, metadata

When you create a field in Salesforce you can make it Required at the object level:

[image]

These required fields then cannot have FLS set via the profile. If you try and set FLS for them via the metadata API you get an error.

So it would be useful to be able to work out which fields are marked as 'Required'.

So how do you do that? There isn't any obvious field for it in the API or the Metadata API.

The [DescribeSObjectResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects_describesobjectresult.htm) has a 'nillable' property fields but that is also set for all checkboxes, so that can't be it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to tell whether a field is required or not in Apex by describe fields](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16101/how-to-tell-whether-a-field-is-required-or-not-in-apex-by-describe-fields)

Comment: @NagendraSingh nillable might be part of the answer, but it isn't the whole answer. For example all checkboxes are 'not nillable' even if they are not required. Perhaps the answer is to look for 'not nillable' fields that do not have a default?

Comment: That is because a checkbox can be either `true` or `false`, it can never be null. And it can never be required, so you can skip it.

Comment: @NagendraSingh indeed, that would be my guess. I'm looking for answers, hopefully with documentation links to back them up

Comment: e.g. is it just checkboxes? Are there any other types that need to be ignored?

Comment: No need of documentation, just try creating a checkbox field, there wont be any `Required` option to select and second there will be only one option to place a default value which can either be `checked` or `unchecked`.

Comment: @NagendraSingh ok then please add that as an answer and lets see if anyone comes up with anything else

Comment: Sigh. Modoverflow, in its wisdom, has closed this one but please note that the answers on the supposed duplicate question are WRONG because they dont account for checkboxes https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/16101/4126

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to this : [How to tell whether a field is required or not in Apex by describe fields](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16101/how-to-tell-whether-a-field-is-required-or-not-in-apex-by-describe-fields) .

As for `Checkbox` can be either true or false, it can never be null and it can never be required, so you can skip it.

Answer (score 1):

First Approach - For the field to be required it has to meet 3 conditions:

```
1   is Creatable
2   is NOT Nillable
3   is NOT Default on create
```

So your if condition should be as following:

```
if(field.isCreateable() && !field.isNillable() && !field.isDefaultedOnCreate()){
// your code
}
```

Once ’field’ is an element while of DescribeFieldResult.

Second Approach - use Database.savePoint(), then try to insert the record, if it fails, retrieve the error of required fields, then use Database.rollback() so the record will not be actually inserted to the DB.